# Removing underscore character from each entry in a list of paths

Tags: ruby, regex

There is an array of strings

```
    paths = ['foo/bar_baz/_sunny', bar/foo_baz/_warm', 'foo/baz/_cold', etc etc]
```

I need to remove underscore in each last part of path (_sunny => sunny, _warm => warm, _cold => cold)

```
    paths.each do |path|
        path_parts = path.split('/')
        path_parts.last.sub!(/^_/, '')
        puts path_parts.join('/')
    end
```

However that solution is a bit dirty. I feel it can be done without using path.split and path.join. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the title for this question to something like "Removing underscore character from each entry in a list of paths" as this is not related to Refactoring in the "altering the internal structure of code without changing its external behavior" sense.

Comment: ok title is changed as you proposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, but the pattern

```
/('[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*\/)_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*')/g
```

could be replaced with

```
'$1$2'
```

if `$x` is used in Ruby to reference matching groups, and `g` is valid flag. It would need to be applied once to the string, with no splits or joins.

Answer (score 2):

Or, more compactly:

```
paths.map {|p| p.sub(/_(?=[^\/]*$)/,"")}
```

That is, strip out any underscore that is followed by any number of non-slashes and then the end of the string...

Comment: very nice! but what does '?=' mean in regexp?

Comment: "`?=`" is a non-matching look-ahead. In that example, it will match "_" only if the next characters are such as indicated, but those next characters won't be part of the match. That way, where "_" gets replaced, you don't need to repeat the characters appearing after it. My own solution could use `?<` and `?=` to avoid having to use groups. It can lead to significant performance gains.